Missing claim when upgrading Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer and System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt
I recently upgraded all nugget package and during that I upgraded these 2 packages:

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer - 6.0.32 --> 8.0.8

System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt - 6.36.0 --> 8.0.2


Post this when I am making api call to service with OAuth2.0 using JWT token my claims sections is coming as null.
Please see the context with old working code:

Now with upgraded version:

I haven't made any other code changes apart from updating Nuget and moving to .net 8.
Please find my code snippet around authorization:
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    AddWebInfrastructure(services);
    AddCustom(services);
    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = CommonConfiguration.Authority;
        options.Audience = ServiceConfiguration.Audience;
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            RoleClaimType = "scope"
        };
    });
    var authorizeRole = ServiceConfiguration.AuthorizeRole;
    var isEnabled = ServiceConfiguration.EnableServiceAuthorization;

    services.AddAuthorization(auth =>
    {
        auth.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();

        auth.AddPolicy("CustomRole", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new CustomRoleRequirement(authorizeRole, isEnabled)));
    });
    services.AddHealthCheck();
}

And for Custom Role Handler:
public class CustomRoleHandler : AuthorizationHandler<CustomRoleRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, CustomRoleRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (!requirement.IsEnabled)
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        var isMatched = context.User.HasClaim(c => c.Type.Equals("scope", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                                         && c.Value.Equals(requirement.Role, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        if (isMatched)
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}


public class CustomRoleRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public CustomRoleRequirement(string role, bool isEnabled)
    {
        Role = role;
        IsEnabled = isEnabled;
    }

    public string Role { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
}

How can I fix this?

Hi Nikhil, please check JwtBearerEvents first, then implement some of them, like  OnAuthenticationFailed.

And I also found maybe it's a known github issue in .net 8, we can fix it by using own TokenHandler.

Please see this link if it helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnet-core/8.0/securitytoken-events#recommended-action
